# Eclipse Showing error when adding D3.js to script folder in the WebContent

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have downloaded the d3.js file from the d3js.org , when i copied this to the script folder in web-content of my Dynamic web project , the js file is red marked , and eclipse complaining  with error : invalid character . How to add this file ? ?

Comment: it showing error on some particular lines , i think those characters are not readable by the eclipse , as it is using UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually created a d3.js file and then copy-pasted the contents of the d3.js file. The charset should be UTF-8 when copying. It worked fine. However, I am getting an error at the first line where you have the "!function() {"

Is the '!' required?

Comment: Another solution is to reference it directly from the website. Add this to your html file: <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8" />

Comment: Yes till now i am doing that only !